# Split each array values and then convert into json in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have array values like this:

```
   Array ( [cont_no] => Array ( [0] => 43-15 [1] => 44-18 )
```

Now I need to split each array values, 43-15 should be split using "-" this key and then convert into JSON type:

```
{"employees":[
    {"cont_no":"43", "repo_id":"15"}, 
    {"cont_no":"44", "repo_id":"18"}, 
]}
```

Comment: See my updated code paste it as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
 $arr = array (cont_no => array ( 0 => '43-15', 1 => '44-18' ));

$finalArr['employees'] = array();

foreach($arr['cont_no'] as $val)
{
    $out = explode('-',$val);
    $finalArr['employees'][]['cont_no'] = $out['0'];
    $finalArr['employees'][]['repo_id'] = $out['1'];
}
echo json_encode($finalArr);
```

Comment: Almost close there $i = 0;
foreach($arr as $val)
{
    $out = explode(',',$val);
    $finalArr['cont_repo'][$i]['cont_no'] = $out['0'];
    $finalArr['cont_repo'][$i]['repo_id'] = $out['1'];
 $i++;
}  ThankYou :) Bro

Comment: "use this" answers are low value on Stack Overflow because they do very little to educate/empower the OP and thousands of researchers.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work

```
$jsonme =["employees"=>[]];
foreach( $ar as $a){
    $vals = explode("-", $a[0]);
    $jsonme["employees"]=[
         "yourkey1" => $vals[0],
        "yourkey2" => $vals[1]
];
$json = json_encode($jsonme);
```

Replace your key for what ever your want it to be in your nested json. (Also, havent tested it but i think its correct)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
json_encode($array[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$src = [ 'cont_no' => [
    '43-15', '44-18'
]];

$target = array_map(
    function($e) {
        return array_combine(
            ['cont_no', 'repo_id'],
            explode('-', $e)
        );
    },
    $src['cont_no']
);


echo json_encode($target);
```

prints

```
[{"cont_no":"43","repo_id":"15"},{"cont_no":"44","repo_id":"18"}]
```

see also:

- http://docs.php.net/array_map
- http://docs.php.net/array_combine
- http://docs.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php