# Convert each array value into json using php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a PHP code that dumps following array:

```
array(4) { 
[0]=> string(79) "https://95.217.21.141/hls/2f04510c8f646cb3e03d5c063b190bd1611847725589-0.m3u8 " 
[1]=> string(79) "https://95.217.21.141/hls/2f04510c8f646cb3e03d5c063b190bd1611847725589-1.m3u8 " 
[2]=> string(79) "https://95.217.21.141/hls/2f04510c8f646cb3e03d5c063b190bd1611847725589-2.m3u8 " 
[3]=> string(78) "https://95.217.21.141/hls/2f04510c8f646cb3e03d5c063b190bd1611847725589-3.m3u8" 
}
```

I want to extract each URL from above array and convert it to JSON. JSON might look like:

```
{"m3u8_1":"https:\/\/95.217.21.141\/hls\/2f04510c8f646cb3e03d5c063b190bd1611847725589-0.m3u8","m3u8_2":"https:\/\/95.217.21.141\/hls\/2f04510c8f646cb3e03d5c063b190bd1611847725589-1.m3u8","m3u8_3":"https:\/\/95.217.21.141\/hls\/2f04510c8f646cb3e03d5c063b190bd1611847725589-2.m3u8","m3u8_4":"https:\/\/95.217.21.141\/hls\/2f04510c8f646cb3e03d5c063b190bd1611847725589-3.m3u8"}
```

I don't know how to convert it into JSON. Also the tricky thing here is, that not every time there would be 4 URLS in array. It might be 1 or 2 or even 5. How do I check that how many URL does array has and then convert it to JSON according to that.

Also I tried searching on stack overflow before putting it here, but I didn't found one that checks and then convert it to JSON

Thanks!

Edit #1

Direct json_encode won't work because PHP does not return values from json which has characters such as `0` `1` `2` `3`

Comment: What's wrong with directly encoding the entire array with `json_encode`?

Comment: It would give wrong JSON. Like with values `0` `1` `2` `3` And PHP does not allow to extract those values from JSON after using `json_decode`

Comment: Ah, I see now. So, basically, what you need is to loop this array and create a new one that has the keys you want. You can use `for` or `foreach`, whatever rocks your boat. But it's pretty basic.

Comment: So you specifically want the key to be `m3u8_1` and `m3u8_2` etc etc

Comment: Is that because of the `.m3u8` at the end of the url? If so could that ever be anything else and would that change the key value you want

Comment: so you want a single object with named keys instead of an array with numbered keys? Why, exactly? This is likely to be more complex for the recipient of the data to process. Especially when what you're proposing is essentially to create keys which are the file extension plus a number. Why not leave it as an array, but extract the file extension from the URL and make that an extra property of each object in in the array? It depends of course on what this data will be used for later, but having some experience of JSON processing, I'd advise that what you're asking for is an unfriendly structure.

Comment: @RiggsFolly No. That would be same. Only number of url might change

Comment: Well thats pretty simple, did you give anything a try

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah i did try from here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28607219/split-each-array-values-and-then-convert-into-json-in-php). But it didn't work. It gave me internal error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would do the trick:

```
$input = [
    "https://95.217.21.141/hls/2f04510c8f646cb3e03d5c063b190bd1611847725589-0.m3u8",
    "https://95.217.21.141/hls/2f04510c8f646cb3e03d5c063b190bd1611847725589-1.m3u8",
     "https://95.217.21.141/hls/2f04510c8f646cb3e03d5c063b190bd1611847725589-2.m3u8",
     "https://95.217.21.141/hls/2f04510c8f646cb3e03d5c063b190bd1611847725589-3.m3u8"
];
$output = [];
$i = 1;
foreach($input as  $url) {
    $output['m3u8_' . $i] = $url;
    $i++;
}
print(json_encode($output));
```